# From STRUCTURE to FSTAT format

Tags: bioinformatics, population-genetics

From numerical simulations I output a file that is input to STRUCTURE ([Hubisz et al. 2009](http://pritchardlab.stanford.edu/publications/pdfs/HubiszEtAl09.pdf)). I now realize that I would need to process my data with FSTAT ([Goudet 1995](http://jhered.oxfordjournals.org/content/86/6/485.short)). Both are text files.

Is there an extant algorithm that would reformat a file that is input to STRUCTURE into a .fstat format?

Comment: What kind of files are these? If they are text files then reformatting would be easy; in that case this question would be off topic.

Comment: Yes these are .txt files. My question is very specific to data format used in bioinformatics though and I am not asking for help to build my own algorithm to reformat but am asking for extant algorithm that would do the job. Does it make my question off-topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PGDSpider](http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/) will do the trick.

PGDSpider is able to parse 31 and to write 35 different file formats including STRUCTURE and .fstat.